# Rails/Postgres query all records created after 5 PM in taking into account daylight savings switch?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am looking to query for all records on a table with a `created_at` time of after 5 PM, EST WITH taking into account daylight savings.

My DB is Postgres and all timestamps are stored in UTC as a normal Rails app.

So, say I have four records

```
ID, created_at, time in EST (-5 offset from UTC),

1, "2017-01-01 22:46:21.829333", 5:46 PM
2, "2017-01-01 21:23:27.259393", 4:23 PM

-------- DST SWITCH -----

ID, created_at, time in EDT (-4 offset from UTC),

3, "2017-03-20 21:52:46.135713", 5:52 PM
4, "2017-06-21 20:08:53.034377", 4:08 PM
```

My query should return records 1 and 3, but should ignore 2 and 4.

I have tried

```
SELECT "id",
       "created_at"
FROM "orders"
WHERE (created_at::TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' > ("created_at"::DATE + TIME '21:00')::TIME AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern')
ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" ASC
```

But this query will return record 1,2,3 when it should not return 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about my previous wrong answer. I don't do much with USA time.

---

> all timestamps are stored in UTC

So `("created_at"::DATE + TIME '21:00')::TIME AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'` actually says it is *utc* time `21:00`, which does not necessarily guarantee it is `5 PM` in EST because the timezone offset changes from 5 to 4. So the compare condition is not correct.

You need to get the local time to make the comparison, rather than the utc time.
Try following code:

```
SELECT
  "id",
  "created_at"
FROM "orders"
WHERE (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'utc' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern') :: TIME > TIME '5:00 PM'
```

Comment: Getting the local time worked! I thought I had tried that originally, but apparently syntax was off.

Comment: As a follow up, how does the `TIME '5:00 PM'` cast actually work, is it using the current timezone of the database itself? Or is it somehow referencing the earlier cast of created at to UTC then to US/Eastern.